# Reload common packages in jupyter

Tags: python, package, jupyter

I ran a jupyter notebook experimenting with `itertools` and accidentally overrode `itertools.tee()` with `None`.

I then tried to reload `itertools` (using `importlib.reload`), didn't work.

Tried to reset the variables using `%reset`, didn't work.

(`%autoreload` obviously won't work because it doesn't involve changes to one of my packages)

Only way I can think of to fix this is to reset the jupyter notebook, works.

But I ask you, kind, good people of Rome, is this sort of thing justified!?
Is there no other way!!??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`itertools` is a built-in module:

```
>>> itertools
<module 'itertools' (built-in)>
```

Therefore, there is no Python file to reload.
You need to restart Python. i.e. do a kernel restart.
Menu: Kernel --> Restart.

Comment: Does this answer your question?